# Setting timezone Interactively in installation via subiquity

Tags: 22.04, timezone, subiquity

Is there a way to select timezone interactively in installation via subiquity?

I'm aware of  'interactive-sections' under which we can set options to select locale and keyboard layouts during setup. However using timezone under the same section is not working as expected

Any suggestions?

Background: I'm trying to create a Ubuntu 22.04 installer based on subiquity

Comment: I think you're referring to Subiquity here, not cloud-init. Subiquity is the installer used for Ubuntu Server. It uses cloud-init and allows a user to pass cloud-init data for automated installations. Cloud-init has no concept of "interactively". It's just a set of services that run on boot. Subiquity has the "interactive-sections" feature. You might get a better response if you update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @falcojr. Edited the question. Hope this makes more sense now